# Howto determine file owner on windows using python without pywin32

Tags: python, windows

I am writing a script which needs to determine the username of the owner of files on windows.

While I found [a solution using pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html) but I am hesitant to use it, as I do not want to add the module dependency.

The script will be written for python 2.6 and has to run on both 32bit and 64 plattforms.

I was wondering if there is a different method, maybe with ctypes, to determine this information

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following uses ctypes to call [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645). Originally it followed the [code snippet](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html) that's linked in the question, but `GetNamedSecurityInfo` is more useful in general than `GetFileSecurity`, especially since it's paired with `SetNamedSecurityInfo` in place of the obsolete function `SetFileSecurity`.

**ctypes and classes**

```
import ctypes as ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes as wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error=True)

ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION  = 0x0001
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    = 0x0002
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND    = 0x0003
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED     = 0x0005
ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 0x0020

SE_FILE_OBJECT = 1
OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001
GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002
DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION  = 0x00000004
SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION  = 0x00000008
LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000010

_DEFAULT_SECURITY_INFORMATION = (OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
    GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
    LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)

LPDWORD = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD)
SE_OBJECT_TYPE = wintypes.DWORD
SECURITY_INFORMATION = wintypes.DWORD

class SID_NAME_USE(wintypes.DWORD):
    _sid_types = dict(enumerate('''
        User Group Domain Alias WellKnownGroup DeletedAccount
        Invalid Unknown Computer Label'''.split(), 1))

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            if value not in self.sid_types:
                raise ValueError('invalid SID type')
            wintypes.DWORD.__init__(value)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.value not in self._sid_types:
            raise ValueError('invalid SID type')
        return self._sid_types[self.value]

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SID_NAME_USE(%s)' % self.value

PSID_NAME_USE = ctypes.POINTER(SID_NAME_USE)

class PLOCAL(wintypes.LPVOID):
    _needs_free = False
    def __init__(self, value=None, needs_free=False):
        super(PLOCAL, self).__init__(value)
        self._needs_free = needs_free

    def __del__(self):
        if self and self._needs_free:
            kernel32.LocalFree(self)
            self._needs_free = False

PACL = PLOCAL

class PSID(PLOCAL):
    def __init__(self, value=None, needs_free=False):
        super(PSID, self).__init__(value, needs_free)

    def __str__(self):
        if not self:
            raise ValueError('NULL pointer access')
        sid = wintypes.LPWSTR()
        advapi32.ConvertSidToStringSidW(self, ctypes.byref(sid))
        try:
            return sid.value
        finally:
            if sid:
                kernel32.LocalFree(sid)

class PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(PLOCAL):
    def __init__(self, value=None, needs_free=False):
        super(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR, self).__init__(value, needs_free)
        self.pOwner = PSID()
        self.pGroup = PSID()
        self.pDacl = PACL()
        self.pSacl = PACL()
        # back references to keep this object alive
        self.pOwner._SD = self
        self.pGroup._SD = self
        self.pDacl._SD = self
        self.pSacl._SD = self

    def get_owner(self, system_name=None):
        if not self or not self.pOwner:
            raise ValueError('NULL pointer access')
        return look_up_account_sid(self.pOwner, system_name)

    def get_group(self, system_name=None):
        if not self or not self.pGroup:
            raise ValueError('NULL pointer access')
        return look_up_account_sid(self.pGroup, system_name)

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376399
advapi32.ConvertSidToStringSidW.errcheck = _check_bool
advapi32.ConvertSidToStringSidW.argtypes = (
    PSID, # _In_   Sid
    ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.LPWSTR)) # _Out_ StringSid

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166
advapi32.LookupAccountSidW.errcheck = _check_bool
advapi32.LookupAccountSidW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # _In_opt_  lpSystemName
    PSID,             # _In_      lpSid
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # _Out_opt_ lpName
    LPDWORD,          # _Inout_   cchName
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # _Out_opt_ lpReferencedDomainName
    LPDWORD,          # _Inout_   cchReferencedDomainName
    PSID_NAME_USE)    # _Out_     peUse

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645
advapi32.GetNamedSecurityInfoW.restype = wintypes.DWORD
advapi32.GetNamedSecurityInfoW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPWSTR,       # _In_      pObjectName
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE,        # _In_      ObjectType
    SECURITY_INFORMATION,  # _In_      SecurityInfo
    ctypes.POINTER(PSID),  # _Out_opt_ ppsidOwner
    ctypes.POINTER(PSID),  # _Out_opt_ ppsidGroup
    ctypes.POINTER(PACL),  # _Out_opt_ ppDacl
    ctypes.POINTER(PACL),  # _Out_opt_ ppSacl
    ctypes.POINTER(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)) # _Out_opt_ ppSecurityDescriptor
```

**functions**

```
def look_up_account_sid(sid, system_name=None):
    SIZE = 256
    name = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(SIZE)
    domain = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(SIZE)
    cch_name = wintypes.DWORD(SIZE)
    cch_domain = wintypes.DWORD(SIZE)
    sid_type = SID_NAME_USE()
    advapi32.LookupAccountSidW(system_name, sid, name, ctypes.byref(cch_name),
        domain, ctypes.byref(cch_domain), ctypes.byref(sid_type))
    return name.value, domain.value, sid_type

def get_file_security(filename, request=_DEFAULT_SECURITY_INFORMATION):
    # N.B. This query may fail with ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION
    # for some filesystems.
    pSD = PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(needs_free=True)
    error = advapi32.GetNamedSecurityInfoW(filename, SE_FILE_OBJECT, request,
                ctypes.byref(pSD.pOwner), ctypes.byref(pSD.pGroup),
                ctypes.byref(pSD.pDacl), ctypes.byref(pSD.pSacl),
                ctypes.byref(pSD))
    if error != 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(error)
    return pSD
```

**example usage**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, sys

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        script_name = os.path.basename(__file__)
        sys.exit('usage: {} filename'.format(script_name))

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    if isinstance(filename, bytes):
        if hasattr(os, 'fsdecode'):
            filename = os.fsdecode(filename)
        else:
            filename = filename.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

    pSD = get_file_security(filename)
    owner_name, owner_domain, owner_sid_type = pSD.get_owner()
    if owner_domain:
        owner_name = '{}\\{}'.format(owner_domain, owner_name)

    print("Path : {}".format(filename))
    print("Owner: {} ({})".format(owner_name, owner_sid_type))
    print("SID  : {}".format(pSD.pOwner))
```

**example output**

```
Path : C:\Users
Owner: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (WellKnownGroup)
SID  : S-1-5-18

Path : C:\ProgramData
Owner: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (WellKnownGroup)
SID  : S-1-5-18

Path : C:\Program Files
Owner: NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller (WellKnownGroup)
SID  : S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464

Path : C:\Windows
Owner: NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller (WellKnownGroup)
SID  : S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for. I only want to lookup some users and groups. I agree that ctypes is not the easiest way to solve the issue, but it prevents additional dependencies and calling external commands using subprocess. Also I have now a real reason to get some practice using ctypes. Many thanks for the references to the MSDN, too.

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` encoding is likely `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`/`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` (ANSI cp), not `sys.stdin.encoding` (OEM cp or whatever `сhcp` returns) -- there are multiple conversions that may loose data (`sys.argv[1]` may be already corrupted). To get the filename as Unicode: `GetCommandLineW()` + `CommandLineToArgvW()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks. I changed it to use "mbcs". To get the native Unicode command line you can also use `win_unicode_console.enable(use_unicode_argv=True)` if you're already using it to get Unicode in the console for older Python versions.

Comment: I notice the section "back references to keep this object alive" in the PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR class. I understand this is to avoid garbage collection, but I do not understand why it is required, can someone clarify?

Comment: Is there any trivial way to know what the valid `system_name` is for a particular file? I seem to need to supply e.g. the IP address of the server if accessing file on a network share to get the owner. Any ideas on how to safely 'automate' what the system name argument should be?

Answer (score 4):

You could invoke a windows shell command "dir /q" and parse the output to find owners.

```
subprocess.call("dir /q", shell=True)
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, but when you need the owner of a lot of files distributed over multiple directories it will require to call the external dir command quite a lot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on certain files, as you get back "..." sometimes via command, yet in windows explorer I see owner.

Comment: Could someone provide a code snippet on how to reliably parse the output?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html) and it seems to me quite easy to implement

```
import win32security

def get_file_owner(file_path:str):
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (file_path, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid (None, owner_sid)
    return name
```

Comment: Does it work? I’m trying to find the Trusted Installer.

Comment: While this answer is useful, it's the same code linked from the question, and uses win32security which comes from pywin32.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be ok even on python 3 adjusting brackets on print
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html

Comment: You mean parenthesis not brackets. Please update your answer.