# In python 3 running on Windows, how do I get the owner of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file-ownership

**Note:** I'm working on Python 3.x on Windows.

I've been working on this for quite a while, and I've found the solution on UNIX systems to be pretty easy.

```
os.stat("filename").st_uid
```

On Windows this just returns `0`

I've found a solution that works sometimes

```
cmd = 'dir /q %s' % "filename"
usr = os.popen(cmd).read().split()[-11]
return usr
```

However, it doesn't always work, sometimes it'll error with the following:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When it does work, it outputs

```
DOMAIN\USERNAME
```

During all of my searching over the past week or so, I've found several solutions that seem to work well in UNIX/LINUX but only the above solution works in Windows, and it's not consistent.

Comment: I don't think that a file has to have an owner in windows.

Comment: Even if I could write a function that would return "owner" or "N/A" if the file doesn't have an owner, that would still work for my purposes. Although, I haven't run into a situation yet where I had to check the ownership of a file and it didn't have one.

Comment: The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086412/4739755) is pretty involved, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: You can easily have `"N/A"`, if that is what you want, with a simple `except IndexError: return "N/A"`... The main question is, can you, for the file which fails, see the owner in Windows Explorer? If yes, you should look for a solution, if not, accept that it has to fail.

Comment: For the ones that fail, I can manually go to the file, and it gives me the owner. For now, I just have it not populate the owner when it fails. So, yes, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: @b_c I don't really completely understand how this works. I got it working by itself, however when I add everything to the larger project, I get the following error `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`. I don't understand enough about what it's doing to troubleshoot it. The error is at `error = advapi32.GetNamedSecurityInfoW(filename, SE_FILE_OBJECT, request,
                ctypes.byref(pSD.pOwner), ctypes.byref(pSD.pGroup),
                ctypes.byref(pSD.pDacl), ctypes.byref(pSD.pSacl),
                ctypes.byref(pSD))`

Comment: Figured out how to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32) to work. My path wasn't a str, so I had to convert it first. I feel really stupid about that. Still, I feel like this is a lot of code to get the owner, but it works.

Comment: @Pyrometheous, that question required using ctypes. You can simplify the solution if PyWin32's win32security module is available.

Comment: Only (potential) downside to that is that it requires a third-party dependency. If you're interested in that approach though, the asked question in that link includes the PyWin32 method (also [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html)), although the example is in python 2.