# How to get userid for the owner in windows?

Tags: python

The program is based on the owner we have to return the absolute path of files from the path specified, the path specified can be from any directory. This program has to be done in python using windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto determine file owner on windows using python without pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32)

Comment: @dboy OP is not talking about file ownership

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This prints out the current working directory, which includes the name of the user which I'm guessing is what you are after.

Comment: for getting user id ?

Comment: Yeah did you try it? I thought you needed the "user id" to construct the absolute path, but this gives you the absolute path directly

Comment: python prog.py /home/user  -owner "deep123"       like this I will be giving in the command-line argument. In my program file I will be giving the path and some owner name based on that it should return the file absolute path.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the username

```
import os
os.getlogin()
```

Comment: for getting the owner id. like pwd will be using for Linux what for windows?

Comment: no this gets you the user name like you asked for. @Mandera has the best way for working directory path