# Get owner of a file using python on windows system

Tags: python, windows

I want to extract the owner of a file within a python3 script on a Windows system.

When I run: `os.path.expanduser(fp)`
or
`os.stat(fp).st_uid`
I receive a `0` for all my discussed files.

Does anybody know how to extract the id or name of an owner of a file using python on windows.

Thanks
-d-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto determine file owner on windows using python without pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pywin32` package:

```bash
$ pip install pywin32
```

and for fetching the `id` or `name of an owner` of a file you can use below code:

```py
import win32security

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(file, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32security

FILENAME = "temp.txt"
open (FILENAME, "w").close ()

print "I am", win32api.GetUserNameEx (win32con.NameSamCompatible)

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner ()
name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid (None, owner_sid)

print "File owned by %s\\%s" % (domain, name)
```

Comment: where can I get the modules win32api, win32con and win32security for python3?