# what is windows equivalent of pwd.getpwuid?

Tags: python

What is the windows equivalent of pwd.getpwuid? I believe pwd is an UNIX package. Here is the code and the error when using windows

```
import pwd
file_owner_name = pwd.getpwuid(file_owner_uid).pw_name

 import pwd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'
```

Comment: This function? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwuid That sounds like it's accessing some fairly Unix-specific storage mechanism. I seriously doubt Windows stores its password database using the exact same C structure and seven fields listed on that documentation. What information do you actually want to get? Because a straightforward "make it look just like Linux" isn't going to happen in this case.

Comment: Thanks Silvio, I bought a book with some codes. The code try to find file owener given file path.   not sure how to change?          file_owner_uid = os.stat(file_path).st_uid
            file_owner_name = pwd.getpwuid(file_owner_uid).pw_name

Comment: Yeah, the issue is Windows just has a totally different file permissions model than Linux. I'm not intimately familiar with the former, but I'm sorry to say your book will likely be of little use here. The code to get detailed information about a file on Windows is going to be pretty different than the equivalent on Linux. I'd go so far as to say completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not supported by Python out of the box. Methods like [`pathlib.Path.owner()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.owner) always return `NotImplementedError` on Windows. You'll need to call Windows functions directly.

---

The easiest way is to install [PyWin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). Then:

```
import win32security
path = './'
security_descriptor = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = security_descriptor.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)
print(f'{domain}\\{name}')
# BOPPREH-DESKTOP\boppreh
```

---

Alternatively, you can use ctypes to avoid an extra dependency, but the code [is *a lot* more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089576/252218), and most mistakes will result in segfaults or unreliable behavior instead of nice exceptions.